# Visual Basic 6.0 IF statement won't go through, only keeps going to ELSE statement

Tags: vb6

I'm trying to compare 2 dates using IF statement but it seems that visual basic won't compare them since i always ended up with the msgbox that is on my Else, here is my code:

```
If Format(theSysDT, "mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM:SS") > Format(CLParamDL, "mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM:SS") Then
        MsgBox ("theSysDt is greater than CLParamDL")
Else
        MsgBox ("error error")
End If
```

theSysDT: 06/21/2021, 15:22:35

CLParamDL: 09/21/2017, 17:02:00

i don't know why it won't enter the IF statement.

Comment: `I'm trying to compare 2 dates` - no, you are trying to compare two strings. Given that you have two dates to begin with (`theSysDT`, `CLParamDL`), it's extra unclear why you would want to specifically ruin them before comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer

Try using format `yyyy/mm/dd` instead of `mm/dd/yyyy` so the date-strings can be sortable in dictionary order.

theSysDT: 06/21/2021, 15:22:35   -> 2021/06/21 15:22:35

CLParamDL: 09/21/2017, 17:02:00  -> 2017/09/21 17:02:00

```
If Format(theSysDT, "yyyy/mm/dd HH:MM:SS") > Format(CLParamDL, "yyyy/mm/dd HH:MM:SS") Then
    MsgBox ("theSysDt is greater than CLParamDL")
Else
    MsgBox ("error error")
End If
```

### Appendix: Frequently Asked Question (about this Answer)

*How come this post is the right answer? Shouldn't we compare two Dates directly?*

Though it looks like the original question was launched to ask "how to **compare** two dates", but actually it's not so. It's a question regarding "how to **canonicalize** date in string format (so it can be compared with other values by using ordinary string comparison operators)". Therefore this post can be the correct answer to be accepted. Showing direct ways to compare two dates makes no sense in this case.

**Interpretation of the original code:**

In general, comparing two dates are to be done by direct comparison of two dates, as every one knows (probably the original poster also knows).

```
If theSysDT > CLParamDL Then
    MsgBox ("theSysDt is greater than CLParamDL")
Else
    MsgBox ("error error")
End If
```

But the original code was not written as such,

```
If Format(theSysDT, "mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM:SS") > Format(CLParamDL, "mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM:SS") Then
    MsgBox ("theSysDt is greater than CLParamDL")
Else
    MsgBox ("error error")
End If
```

Because it is a `minimal test code` to clarify the problem, "why date-**strings** cannot be compared as expected". The code is clearly showing both `how date-strings are composed` and `how comparison is made`. Since all the elements were packed (too) compactly in a single `IF` clause, it looks like an awkward code for attempting to use string comparison to compare two dates. But it's a right code which was purposefully designed as such. It's important for us to grasp the entire picture correctly by seeing the original question without prejudice.

Comment: It is a very wrong advice to convert two dates to two strings for the purpose of comparing them. The code should have been `If theSysDT > CLParamDL Then`.

Comment: I fully agree with @GSerg. And it's not even a `String` comparison, as the `Format` variation used is the `Variant` one, which might or might not result in a correct comparison. If the two dates might be of different type, like a VB `Date` and a Win32 `FILETIME` structure, it would be better to convert one to the other [(Win32 API `SystemTimeToVariantTime`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleauto/nf-oleauto-systemtimetovarianttime) and compare those.

Comment: Nothing wrong. For the question with `minimal, reproducible example`, I posted a minimal suggestion to make the code snippet work. Since the questioner asked why `IF` condition with string comparison doesn't work as expected, I indicated that strings might not be composed properly. Though I know possibility to compare Date values directly in this case, but I chose the solution to modify format string, respecting questioner's **will** to use `Format()` function and string comparison. If you have a better solution, just post it.

Comment: @ardget: while your answer is _technically_ correct, it enforces bad habits. I thought SO as a community thrives to provide _better_ answers rather than _technically_ correct ones. As for the OP's **will**: he stated he wants to compare **dates**, but posted a **string** comparison instead. You know as well as I do that inexperienced programers come up with strange solutions for new problems, applying current knowledge. So let us show them something new and better for what they're trying to do. At least I personally appretiate new knowledge acquired that way.

Comment: The use of parentheses around the MsgBox strings makes the code just that much scarier.

Comment: @HelO'Ween & Ardget: I have to agree - partly - to both of you. While Hel´s answer could lead the OP to learn how to debug (e.g. outputting the two strings before compare ... if he tries to learn) the more elegant solution is Ardget´s.

Comment: @nabuchodonossor There is nothing elegant in `If Format(one_int, "0000000000") > Format(another_int, "0000000000") Then`. It is confusing and wrong, despite it produces the same result as the correct `If one_int > another_int Then`. This code is exactly that.

Comment: The goal is not comparing 2 dates. Interpreting the first line of the original post as "trying to compare 2 date-**strings**", I had found the whole question (including title, explanation, code and other statements) look consistent. Therefore I took the question as such and wrote the answer. If you do have a better answer, please post it **separately**.

Comment: @Bob77 From cross platform developer's perspective, extra brackets are indispensable to keep code-**text** portable to other languages (mainly to c-like coding style languages). Conversions from `statements ...`  to `function_calls(...)` are very laborious tasks which cannot be done at once by `find & replace`, even with helps of regular-expressions.

Comment: Okay, everyone. I summarized some points in the FAQ. Please read it carefully, if you haven't yet understood why this is the right answer. I wonder why I have to write so much text not for OP but for the audience. thank you.

Comment: @ardget Poor excuse, and it has a penalty.  There are lots of pitfalls in such pidgin-VB.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming theSysDT and CLParamDL are both of type Date, then just compare them without trying to convert them to strings:

```
If theSysDT > CLParamDL Then
    MsgBox ("theSysDt is greater than CLParamDL")
Else
    MsgBox ("error error")
End If
```